# Excel Copy and Paste Merged Cells into Single-Cell Format

Tags: excel, formatting, copy, paste, cells

I'm trying to copy over some data from a set of merged cells into a single cell format. I don't know how to do this.

I'm trying to copy this:

[image]

This is what I get when I paste it:

[image]

This is what I want to happen when I paste it:

[image]

Since my merged cells "are" single cells, I wish they would paste like single cells. I haven't found a solution anywhere. I know that you can Special Paste values, but that doesn't keep the formatting that I need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you unmerge the cells before you copy them?  If you need to leave the original cells as is, make your copy to the right of your data, unmerge the pasted cells and then copy that into your destination column (looks like L).

Comment: Can't you just unmerge after the copy?

Comment: Yes, I can unmerge after the copy. However, I would like it to keep the formatting as if the merged cell were a single cell. As in, when I paste it, it would just paste into a single column with the formatting properties that it has (centered, and with the borders). Simply unmerging after does not keep it centered, and it places the border way over. My goal is to make this fast.

Answer (score 3):

If you paste your selection, you'll notice a small blue icon at the bottom left of the pasted range. Click on it and select the third icon "Formulas & Number Formats":
[image]

This should do the job!